# Update Lead/Contact record email values to Null in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, field-update, sales-cloud

I'm going through a process where I take a segmented amount of records that are in the 'Held' status in all subscribers and update their Email fields in Sales Cloud to NULL values so they can be replaced in the future. Then their statuses would be reset to 'Active' once they're replaced.

The problem is I'm trying to use journey builder with contact/lead activities to update the email address values, but it doesn't look like it accepts null values and putting in dummy emails goes against what I've built so far.

Is there a way to update contact/lead records in sales cloud with null values through journey builder that I haven't thought of or through a different method in marketing cloud?

UPDATE (3/15/2023):
I got it to work running this script:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    try {
        var ampscript = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByID("CONTENT_BLOCK_ID");
        Write(Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(ampscript));
    } catch (ex) {
        var logDE = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENTION_NAME");
        logDE.Rows.Add({ErrorMessage: Stringify(ex), Timestamp: Now()});
    }
</script>
```

And it's tied to this AMPscript:

```
%%[
    VAR @dataExtensionName, @dataExtensionRows, @row, @leadId

    SET @dataExtensionName = "DATA_EXTENTION_NAME"
    SET @dataExtensionRows = LookupRows(@dataExtensionName,"FIELD_NAME","FIELD_VALUE")

    FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@dataExtensionRows) DO
        SET @row = Row(@dataExtensionRows,@i)
        SET @leadId = Field(@row,"SubscriberKey")
        UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@leadId,"fieldsToNull","Email")
    NEXT @i
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible through Journey Builder, but it's definitely possible using `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` and AMPScript.

Here is an example that sets the email address to null by using the `fieldToNull` as an identifier for the column to update:

```
SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact", @PersonContactId, "OptedIn", "True", "fieldsToNull", "EmailAddress")
```

Don't forget to update fields names...

Comment: Thanks Rachid, I'm only used to implementing AMPScript in cloud pages and emails, how would I be able to passively use AMPScript for the records I'm looking to update without engaging with them?

Comment: For example, using an automation, create an SQL activity to store your audience inside a data extension, then use a script activity to execute AMPScript you have in a content block. More about this here https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/use-ampscript-to-enhance-ssjs-in-sfmc/

Comment: Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.